# Vuex (Vue 3) не вижу данные в getters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Есть модуль `authModule`, в определенный момент помещаю в него данные о пользователе:

```
this.$store.commit('authModule/setUser', userInfo)
```

Данные успешно записываются в state (проверял через Vue Devtools)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, в другом компоненте, пытаюсь получить данные:

```
mounted() {
    // через ...mapGetters() тоже самое
    const user = this.$store.getters['authModule/getUser']
    console.log(user)
}
```

Обращение происходит, но в ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам модуль:

```
export const authModule = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    auth: false,
    user: {}
  }),
  getters: {
    getAuth: (state) => state.auth,
    getUser: (state) => state.user
  },
  mutations: {
    setAuth: (state, auth) => state.auth = auth,
    setUser: (state, user) => state.user = user
  },
  actions: {
    async checkRole({ commit, state }, roles) {
      console.log(state.user.DB) // Так тоже не видит данные
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну, это Proxy-обертка типичная для Vue3. Она отвечает за реактивность. Так в чем конкретно проблема? Если хочешь вывести в лог значение, а не использовать его в выражении - скопируй/сериализуй его. А в выражениях, должно работать "как обычная переменная".

Comment: @yar85 я понимаю что это обертка, но я не могу обратиться дальше по ключу, например к Role, выдает undefined. Просто все остальные такие случаи с другими getters работают нормально, я могу поместить их в переменную и использовать дальше, а тут нет

Comment: По всей видимости, просто данные не успевали там появиться. `setTimemout(() => { const user = this.$store.getters['authModule/getUser']
    console.log(user) }, 0)` показывает данные

Comment: А, вроде понял. Если данные получаемые геттером обновляются асинхронно (например, с ответом сервера или по действию пользователя), то стоит использовать подписку на мутации: все-таки компоненты разные, порядок может нарушаться. Если же синхронно вызываешь `commit` и точно **после** этого геттер возвращает пустой объект юзера - то это уже странно, и тогда нужен воспроизводимый пример (где будет и вызов мутации, и обращение через геттер. Тут у нас только кусочки компонентов, не совсем ясно как это работает в сборе: когда выполняется запись, и когда чтение).

Comment: Сами по себе мутации синхронны (это прописано в документации), то есть мы можем сразу исключить как причину сами библиотеки Vuex и Vue: ошибка явно где-то в приложении. Вероятно не в коде, а в том как/когда он вызывается. Рассогласование, проще говоря: один компонент предполагает результаты действий другого компонента, но "не знает" были ли эти действия выполнены... таких ситуаций желательно избегать.